# Unable to build on TFS a .NET core SPA with angular 6.1.0

Tags: asp.net, angular, tfs, azure-devops

I'm having a .NET core app spa with angular 6.1.0 . Running the build on the local machine works well. When i'm trying to do this on a TFS build definition i'm getting the following errors (and not only these).

I have a second .NET core app with angular 5, everything works well. I think i finished google with seeking and i found nothing helpful.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If it works well on your dev machine and not works fine from a TFS server build. Very likely the environment problem.

To make sure the build successful, you should **keep your build server environment the same with your local environment**. Please double check this, such as same Visual Studio version.

For trouble shooting, you could try to remote to your build agent manually run your build and test on your build agent.

According to your error looks like that is not coping npm modules during your build process. Also check if you npm install task, if corresponding package installed properly.

Besides, also set `system.debug=true` to see if there are some useful info for future troubleshooting.

Comment: where should i put system.debug=true

Comment: @TrulyXax In build pipeline variable. Check Enable Verbose Debug Mode for TFS Build vNext for details https://www.benday.com/2016/09/19/enable-verbose-debug-mode-for-tfs-build-vnext/

Comment: thanks, i'm getting more log now but nothing is useful. And no, i'm haven't a npm install task before the build task .

Comment: @TrulyXax Thanks for your update. Then combine your error info. You may have to use a npm task in the pipeline to download those module files unless you already check in them into source control. Running the build on the local machine works well. Because of you local already have these folders. However you build agent do not have (or  not in corresponding agent work folder). So you need to add a npm install task to download them.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/npm?view=azure-devops